# ILogger to blob storage is slow

Tags: performance, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have a function that makes various LogWarning calls, using the ILogger capability from Microsoft. When deployed to Azure Services, this will write log data to blobs. It seems to be slowing down my application a lot, which I guess is the nature of having to send traffic over network to the storage unit.

I am trying to work out -- Is ILogger something I can run asynch so it is faster? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi Steve, have you found a solution by directly using ILogger in async mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer. For azure web app, we usually use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) for logging. It's actually using async mode for logging.

The benefits:

1.Easy to setup and integrated with ILogger.

2.You can control the log level.

3.You can also export the logs from Application insights to blob storage.